# Mimicking a file format that is actually a zip

Tags: file-format

Backstory: I have been trying to find a way to automatically turn batches of photos into WhatsApp stickers. I was able to do that, but now I am trying to figure out a way to actually import them into WhatsApp. For that, I am trying to piggyback off an app which can import it's own sticker pack files, with extension *.wastickers*
([example here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kYD7Ifq-4pLdw_bzm9vozPP2ix2Orc6s)).  The app can be found [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.marsvard.stickermakerforwhatsapp&hl=en).

Upon inspection with *file*, the format turns out to be a .zip archive (and indeed it unzips). Binwalk can also see all of the files inside the archive without unzipping it. As such I tried mimicking the contents of the container and zipping it with 0 compression ratio ("storage" mode) and changing the extension, but the app does not see the archive as a legitimate stickerpack. Furthermore binwalk can't see the contents of such an archive off the bat.

What is contained inside an archive: a png called 0, which is the stickerpack icon; A bunch of .webp files numbered from 1 to at most 30, and two text files, *title.txt* and *author.txt* which, you guess it, denote the title and the author of the stickerpack.

What is special about their container? How can I mimick it?

Comment: in the example file, one thing that sticks out is the files have absolute paths starting at `/`, e.g. `/1.webp` ...  normally when you zip a file you end up with relative paths, e.g. `1.webp`

Comment: [`zipnote`](https://manpages.debian.org/zip/zipnote.1) can change the name (the path) of a file inside a zip. But in my tests it would want to do that only one at a time. Perhaps zipnote is a bit frail.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about emulating  a file format for WhatsApp

Comment: You're right, this might not be the best place to ask. Perhaps someone with enough reputation could migrate it to the Reverse Engineering Stack Exchange?